# How can I facet wrap for specific categorical values of multiple variables in Shiny?

Tags: r, variables, shiny, facet-wrap

as part of my research, I'm designing a Shiny app that allows visualization of a big pile of data. However, right now I'm working on the base of the app. For my app, I want the user to facet wrap just for specific categorical values of a variable. I'm working on a meta-analysis so I'm sure the number of categorical values will increase. Therefore, it would be much easier to look at a few values instead of all of them. Anyways, this is how my data looks like:

```
ABXID | ANIMALID | TIME | TLD | DV | DOSEMGKG | SPECIES | SUBSPECIES | AGE | PLATFORM | MUTATION
```

I know there's a lot of data, but it's all useful. **So, for example the platform variable has different values, three to be exact: Duobody, Hexabody and Bispecific. I want the user to choose what type of antibody platform they want to be displayed and even more than just 1.** Not only will I be doing this for PLATFORM, but also for the other variables, allowing the user to really see what they want. My Shiny app looks like this:

Note: I have only written the conditionPanels for PLATFORM and MUTATION, because I think it would be easy to see if it would work and if anyone could help me.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Tab 1",
                         
        titlePanel("Shiny App: Concentration vs Time Graphs"),
                         
         sidebarLayout(
            mainPanel("Concentration vs Time graphs", plotOutput(outputId = "plot")),
            sidebarPanel(helpText("This app is developed to visualize pharmacokinetic data of different antibodies..."),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "study",
                label = "Include study:",
                choices = c("GLP Toxicity" = "ME1044-011", "Dose Range Finding", "Single Dose", "Repeat Dose"),
                selected = "ME1044-011",
                multiple = T
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "x",
                label = "X-axis:",
                choices = c("Time" = "TIME", "TLD"),
                selected = "Time"
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = 'column',
                label = "Columns for:",
                choices = c("Dose mg/kg" = "DOSEMGKG", "Species" = "SPECIES", "Antibody" = "ABXID", "Subspecies" = "SUBSPECIES", "Age" = "AGE", "Animal ID" = "ANIMALID"),
                selected = "DOSEMGKG"
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = 'row',
                label = "Rows for:",
                choices = c("Dose mg/kg" = "DOSEMGKG", "Species" = "SPECIES", "Antibody" = "ABXID", "Subspecies" = "SUBSPECIES", "Age" = "AGE",  "Animal ID" = "ANIMALID", "Platform" = "PLATFORM"),
                selected = "ABXID"
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.row == 'PLATFORM'",
                selectInput(
                    inputId = 'platform',
                    label = "Choose platform(s)",
                    choices = c("Hexabody", "Duobody", "Bispecific"), multiple = T
                 )
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                conditoin = "input.row == 'Mutation'",
                selectInput(
                    inputId = 'mutation',
                    label = "Choose mutation(s):",
                    choices = c('M1', "M2", "M3"), multiple = T
                )
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "group",
                label = "Group by:",
                choices = c("Dose mg/kg" = "DOSEMGKG", "Species" = "SPECIES", "Antibody" = "ABXID", "Subspecies" = "SUBSPECIES", "Age" = "AGE",  "Animal ID" = "ANIMALID"),
                selected = "ANIMALID"
            ),
            sliderInput(
                inputId = 'trange',
                label = "Time range:",
                min = 0,
                max = 1704,
                value = c(0, 1704 )
            )
                    ))
                         
    )),
    
    
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Tab 2",
                         
        titlePanel("Tab 2"),
                         
            sidebarLayout(
                mainPanel("Plot #2", plotOutput(outputId = "plot2")),
                    sidebarPanel(helpText("Whatever text..."),
                        selectInput(
                        inputId = 't',
                        label = "Example",
                        choices = c("#1", "#2", "#3"),
                        selected = "#1"
                        )
                             )
                         )))
)
```

This is the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = input$x, y = "DV", col = input$group)) + xlab("Time") + ylab("Concentration (ug/mL)") +
            geom_point() + facet_grid(get(input$row) ~ get(input$column)) + scale_x_continuous(limits = input$trange) + 
            scale_color_viridis(discrete = T) + theme_bw() })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Anyways, I really hope someone can help me with this question, as I'm fairly new to Shiny and still am learning things. So with the conditionPanel, a selectInput will appear if the user clicks on the variable, allowing them to choose what value they want to be displayed. That's how I want them to use the app. I hope the helpful readers get my question!

I have tried facet_wrap(), but that is showing me all the values of course. I'm not familiar with other options. Anyways, I hope I can just facet_wrap() for specific values of a variable that the user has chosen, even if it's more than 1.

Comment: If you just want to show some categories then you have to filter the dataset according to the user's choice before plotting.

Comment: Package {trelliscopejs} might be useful if you plan heavy interactive filtering and facetting: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trelliscopejs/vignettes/trelliscopejs.html

Comment: @stefan thanks, that is indeed a good option.

Comment: @stefan should I do this with a reactive function?

Comment: Personally I would use a reactive to filter the data. Even if it is just for reasons of  clarity of your code and app. IMHO that's especially important if an app grows larger.